# Explain why 60.61.62.63/26 is not a valid host IP address?

Tags: ip, ip-address

Can anyone Explain why 60.61.62.63/26 is not a valid host IP address? Shall be very thank full to you.

Comment: It's not a host address as such, but a range of addresses 60.61.62.0 - 60.61.62.63

Comment: @Zain you should mark the correct answer below, now that a year has passed

Answer (score 10):

It's a broadcast address. All the host bits are 1.

```
/26 = 255.255.255.192
192 = 11000000
 63 = 00111111
```

Answer (score 1):

It is valid, but it is not a **host** IP-Address. In Network you have a similar format for describing hosts and sets of hosts. Anything which has the `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/xxx` format is specifying subnets not host. In your case `60.61.62.63/26` specifies a subnet with 64 hosts.

Comment: actually, it's perfectly normally to use CIDR syntax for a host address so as to indicate the related subnet mask.  It's just that in this case the specified address is a broadcast address, and therefore not usable.